# Iterate through fields of a composite type in Julia

Tags: julia

What is the best way to iterate through the fields of a composite (user-defined) type in Julia?

Let's say, I defined the following struct and created an instance:

```
struct Foo
    bar
    baz::Int
    qux::Float64
end
foo = Foo("Hello, world.", 23, 1.5)
```

How can I iterate through all fields and for example print the fields and their values to the REPL? I have a type with several fields and I don't want to explicitly name every one. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`fieldnames(typeof(foo))` gives you an `Vector{Symbol}` for the names, and `foo.` lowers to `getfield(foo,...)`. So you just:

```
julia> for n in fieldnames(typeof(foo))
           println(getfield(foo,n))
       end
Hello, world.
23
1.5
```

this is obviously not good for performance since type inference cannot occur here (the type that you are getting the field from depends on the value `n`).

Answer (score 0):

For only the values also

```
for k in 1:length(fieldnames(foo))
    println(getfield(foo,k))
end
```

seems to work (Julia 5.1). Still no type inference, but avoiding the Symbol lookup.

Comment: This syntax is now outdated.